# How to handle intermittent alert in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, alert

I have automation scenario that sometimes the system return javascript alert and sometimes not at all. I don't know what the cause of this, probably the network issue. I already create the alert handler for this:

```
public boolean isAlertPresent() {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    return true;
}
```

I call this in one of my step that sometimes appear alert:

```
public WSSPage enterAndSearchContent(String title) throws InterruptedException {
    waitForElementTextWithEnter(searchTextField, title);
    while (isAlertPresent()){
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.dismiss();
        break;
    }
    return PageFactory.initElements(driver, WSSPage.class);
}
```

The problem is when the alert doesn't show up, it will give me NoAlertPresentException, and the automation result will be failed. I want the code to move on if the alert doesn't happen by moving to the next line, in this case it will just return `PageFactory.initElements(driver, WSSPage.class);`
Can you help me provide a better code from this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you consider changing `while (isAlertPresent())` to `if (isAlertPresent())` ? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB I did. and it still gives NoAlertException when there's no alert.

Comment: Why would you always `return true;` from `public boolean isAlertPresent()`? If no alert present can we return `false`? Try returning a `boolean` value back from `public boolean isAlertPresent()`. Based on the return type we will handle the situation in `enterAndSearchContent()`. Thanks

Comment: I guess, murthi solution would work for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavascriptExecutor worked for you. Just take care that you should execute it before clicking the event which invoke alert.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }");
```

Note :- do not use it after clicking on event which invoke alert confirmation box. Above code by default set the confirmation box as true means you are accepting/click on ok on all confirmation box on that page if invoked

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: whoa... this is works for me. I don't even need to use alert handler anymore. Thank you so much!

Comment: already upvote it but sadly I don't have enough reputation to make publicly displayed in your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: no problem .. you now just need 2 points for the Privilege ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the method isAlertPresent as given below and try it. It may help you.

```
public boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try{
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
       return true;
    }
    catch (NoAlertPresentException noAlert) {
      return false;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException timeOutEx){
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: it did not work, I think because the `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());` will throw exception when there is no alert.

Comment: Normally, Expected conditions will throw Timeout Exception. You can try with that. I have updated the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

You can include that particular exception in try catch. Then the exception will be catched and will not through any error and your execution will continue.
Also create a implicit wait to handle this with less timestamp.